# Matlab : findpeaks with flat regions

Tags: matlab, curve

I have data which contains peaks that I want to detect with the function **findpeaks** from the Signal Processing Toolbox, in Matlab.

You will understand my problem with some images :
[image: My signal in red, peaks in blue]

-> Here you have my data in red, and the finding peaks in blue ; with this code :

```
[peakHeight, peakLocation] = findpeaks(data,'minPeakHeight',4.3);
```

I wanted to only keep the first ones (yellow circles).
Sometimes, the first peak in my "red block" is not at the yellow circles location, like this :

[image: The peak is not at the start of the red block]

I tried many parameters of findpeaks, like *'MinPeakProminence','Threshold' and 'MinPeakDistance'*, but the best I obtain is this, with `findpeaks(data,'minPeakHeight',4.3,'MinPeakProminence',4);` :

[image: Not the good peaks]

As my peaks in my data are not really flat, I don't always keep the first good ones.
In my research I found and tried this : `islocalmax(data,'FlatSelection','first');`, but it doesn't work well too.

To sum up, I want to have one peak for every "red block". And these peaks need to be just after the rise.
So please, have you some idea to solve my problem ? Thanks :)

Comment: Can you just do some simple loop over all of the peaks and remove those which come too soon after the previous one?

Comment: I tried, but I see after that many peaks are not well detected at the location I want (cf the edit of my post, sorry for my bad explanation and thanks for your idea!)

Comment: Can you just find values above some threshold if they're as consistent as in your answer? That would be simpler than finding the peak. It's unclear what your expected behaviour is for the edit, if the blue peak starts later than the red, and you don't have the red, then how are you supposed to know that? Or if you do have the red then why is the blue useful at all when you can just detect a rise in the red?

Comment: Really sorry if my demand is not clear. As I just wanted to have the location of the firsts rises in the red (my data), I thought that findpeaks (in blue) was the solution. If not, how do you think I could achieve that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you just need to detect the points where the input data crosses some threshold, in your example this threshold might be 4.

For example:

```
% Create some dummy data
x = linspace(0,9,1000);
y = rand(size(x))/10 + 4.5*(mod(round(x),3)==1);
y = movmean(y, [3, 3] );

% Set a threshold
thresh = 4;
% Check when the signal exceeds this threshold
overThresh = y > thresh;
% Get the indicies where the threshold exceeding region starts
bRisingEdge = [false, diff(overThresh)>0];
% Get the x & y values at the rising edge
yRising = y(bRisingEdge);
xRising = x(bRisingEdge);

% Plot the results to confirm
figure(1); clf; plot( x, y, 'r' );
hold on; plot( xRising, yRising, 'ko', 'markersize', 10 );
```

[image: plot]